# Python splitting text returns a str and a list of str

Tags: parsing, python-3.x, text

I wonder whether someone can help me with the syntax to split my text file into key, value pairs.

```
Abbasso: termine con cui si indicano gli ambienti situati sotto il ponte di coperta. 
Abbattuta: manovra che consiste nel puggiare sino a fare prendere il vento alle vele sulle mure opposte. 
Abbisciare: (fr.: prendre la biture; ingl.: to coil) stendere un cavo o una catena come fosse una biscia in modo da evitare che si imbrogli successivamente, quando sarà posto in opera. 
Abbordo: (fr.: abordage; ingl.: collision) collisione in mare. Sinonimo, poco usato, di accosto e di abbordaggio. 
Abbrivo: (fr.: erre; ingl.: way-on) inerzia dell'imbarcazione a continuare nel suo movimento anche quando è cessata la spinta propulsiva, sia essa a vela che a motore. 
Abbuono: (fr.: bonification, rating; ingl.: rating) compenso: (o vantaggio) dato ad una imbarcazione per permetterle di gareggiare più equamente: (ad esempio abbuono per anzianità di costruzione dello scafo).
```

My function at the minute gives me a key str, but a value type(list). Instead I want the value also to be a str. I get what my problem is  that what should a be the value is splitting on every colon instead of only on the leftmost colon.

```
def create_dict():
   eng_fr_it_dict={}
    f_name = "dizionario_della_vela.txt"

    handle = open(f_name, encoding = 'utf8')
    for line in handle:
        #print(line)
        if line.startswith(" ") : continue
        line.lstrip()
        terms = line.split(": ")
        #print(terms[1:])       
        term = terms[0].lstrip()
        expan = terms[1:]
        print(type(term), type(expan))
        eng_fr_it_dict[term] = eng_fr_it_dict.get(term, expan)

    with open("eng_fr_it_dict.txt", "wb") as infile:
        pickle.dump(eng_fr_it_dict,infile)

    print(eng_fr_it_dict)
```

Can you suggest a cleverer way to do this or will I have to work out how to covert the list of str to a single str? I thought that there was a split in-built function, but obviously not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
file = open("dizionario_della_vela.txt", "r")
data = file.read()
file.close()
data = data.split("\n") # getting every line as seperate list
myDict = {}
for line in data:
    line = line.split(":")
    key = line[0] # getting first element as key
    value = ":".join(line[1:]) # joins elements (starting with second) with 
                               # ":". We need this because previous line 
                               # was splitted by ":" to get your key. This
                               # is where "string" value is produced.
    myDict[key] = value

for key in myDict.keys():
    print(myDict[key])
```